# Where can I obtain nightly-builds of LibreOffice?

Tags: package-management, ppa, libreoffice

Is there a PPA with nightly builds of LibreOffice? Or some another source that I can add to my sources.list such that I can try nightly-builds of LibreOffice?

I know about the various ways to get the nightlies manually, but I want that the builds are updated with the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the PPA available here: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa

The description of the PPA reads as thus:

> LibreOffice test builds and backports
>
> Most of the packages in this ppa have only experienced minor testing
>   -- in fact it is the place to enable a wider audience to test packages before they are published into the distro proper. In general this ppa
>   is *not* for the average user to install without a closer look (if it
>   would be, its packages would be in the main repositories).

Refer to [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) for instructions on how to add the PPA to your computer.

Comment: I found that PPA but there is 3.4.4 the last version. Nightlys tends to go to 3.5 at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Up to now there has not been a PPA providing this because of the complexities inherited from the old OOo build.

With the 3.5/precise release both the upstream build system and the packaging at Debian and Ubuntu have been cleared up enough to make this basically feasable -- if excluding l10n, binfilter and mozilla. Such a PPA would still likely burst default size limitations within one month and still hug a builder machine for >3 hours (on a fast builder) because there is no easy way to reuse a ccache in a ppa -- so I guess there is some clearance needed for this additional resource use.

Next question would be what to build as there are at least two/three active branches all the time. For example right now:

- the first being master which will be in the p+1/LibreOffice 3.6 release
- the second libreoffice-3-5 which will be in the precise/LibreOffice 3.5 release
- the third being libreoffice-3-4 which was in the oneiric/LibreOffice 3.4 release

Master is obviously the most interesting, but for QA the release branch (which will be in the next Ubuntu release) can also be interesting.

So even with this, there is a lot of details to work out (like versionnames to use etc.). If you are interested, I would be glad to help out though!

Answer (score 1):

### LibreOffice does not provide any nightly PPA, unfortunately.

It seems that for such a large project with multiple branches, doing this would be difficult: [reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/96680/1992).

For now the only option for daily builds is to use the manual installation options. This answer could be updated in the future if the situation changes.

---

> To clarify I wrote this answer because I was looking for the same
> thing and confirmed that the situation is still the same as it was
> when the other answers were written.

---

Perhaps someone could build a weekly/biweekly/monthly build solution, but a nightly build PPA is not going to happen, it seems.